How exactly do linkers find the symbol of a R_RISCV_PCREL_HI20I relocation, given a R_RISCV_PCREL_LO12 relocation?
This is a followup question to What do %pcrel_hi and %pcrel_lo actually do?. I'm writing a simple Risc-V linker, and I'm trying to understand how, given an R_RISCV_PCREL_LO12I relocation, the symbol of the corresponding R_RISCV_PCREL_HI20 relocation is found.
For concreteness, here is a RiscV instruction sequence, with relocations interleaved:
1: auipc x10,%pcrel_hi(some_symbol)
      R_RISCV_PCREL_HI20   some_symbol
   lw    x11,%pcrel_lo(1b)(x10)
      R_RISCV_PCREL_LO20I  1b    // symbol refers to the auipc instruction above.

Imagine what the linker does when encountering the ...LO12I relocation.
For this particular relocation type, it looks up the symbol 1b, which gives it the location
of the auipc instruction. However, the linker also needs the symbol some_symbol associated
with the auipc instruction. As far as I can tell, there is no direct way to
find that some_symbol. The reason is that the ELF spec as far as I'm able to tell
doesn't provide a mapping symbol => relocations_using_that_symbol.
We only have a relocation => symbol mapping.
There must be a function which, given a symbol (like 1b) from a ...LO12I relocation,
yields the corresponding ...HI20 relocation. How is this function typically
implemented? Does the linker need to build a special table of R_RISCV_PCREL_HI20
relocations, indexed by symbols? Or is there a more clever way of locating, for a
given ...LO12I relocation, the corresponding ...HI20 relocation?

Ok, obviously I’m missing sthg.  %hi & %lo should be used both referencing the same symbol (and offset), no?

No, for ...PCREL_LO12I the Risc-V PSABI spec states that the symbol in the relocation is referring to the associated ("paired"?) auipc instruction, to which ...PCREL_HI20 applies. It looks like a hack, but I've confirmed this via various searches.

Ok, so 1b refers to another relocation?

How does the assembler associate a %hi in one instruction with %lo in a later instruction and still generate such relocations?

From the spec: The ...PCREL_LO12_I or ...PCREL_LO12_S relocations contain a label pointing to an instruction in the same section with an ...PCREL_HI20 relocation entry that points to the target symbol:
At label:
...PCREL_HI20 relocation entry → symbol
...PCREL_LO12_I relocation entry → label
To get the symbol address to perform the calculation to fill the 12-bit immediate on the add, load or store instruction the linker finds the ~...PCREL_HI20relocation entry associated with theAUIPC` instruction.

What I'm after is the "finds the ...PCREL_HI20 relocation associated with the AUIPC instruction". How does "finds" work? Are there data structures in the ELF file that assist with this, or is the onus placed on the linker to maintain its own data structure to provide this mapping?

Ok, can you post an assembly example and a disassembly of same?

Is it the 1b that is the offset to the auipc?

Yes, the 1b refers to the auipc. Here is a sample, where sym is at address 0x20004:
1:
auipc x4,%pcrel_hi("sym")
addi x4,x4, %pcrel_lo(1b)
m.auipc(4, m.pcrel_hi("sym"))
Disassembly after using my tool + Reko as a disassembler:
00000000: 00020217 auipc tp,0x20
00000004: 00420213 addi tp,tp,0x4


Ok, so it looks like when looking at the (relocation for) instruction with the %lo, the linker has to find the auipc, and its relocation to find the symbol.  It then has symbol, and a pc address (addr of auipc) (and maybe an offest) to compute the %lo value?
